# Azure PostgreSql Connection FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "xyz", database "xyz", SSL on

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, asp.net-core

[image]

I have tries two different tools (PostgreSql, Azure Data) with the connect the database but the same error throw.

Comment: you need to edit your pg_hba.conf and have to add an enrty for the host "xx.xx.xx.xx" and then need to restart the postgres service.

Comment: Yeah, I have already setup this file but can't access the Azure ProsgreSQL database

Comment: 1. Looks like you have SSL=on in postgresql.conf
2. also what is the values of listen_addresses in postgresql.conf ? default should be *
3. Try to connect the database locally first using the local ip

Comment: May be client has not given permission in my public IP address.

Comment: @PurveshPatel Could you please provide the firewall configuration of the database?

Comment: @JimXu - Sorry, I can't give you this information.

Comment: "Yeah, I have already setup this file"  Please show us.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/u6riad - 

Check my screenshot and let me know it is correct or not?

Answer (score -2):

Below configuration solve the error for me.

In Azure Postgres, navigate `Server parameters` -> search `require_secure_transport` -> set to `off`.